# INFORMIX -> INSERT data to a table and file both

Tags: informix

We need to INSERT data to a table and the same time we need the same data to write to a file.

We cannot do this activity from the application end since there are different types of applications doing the INSERT operation.

So, we have to run this activity from DB end only.

Thanks !

Best Regards,
Sams

We have tried a INSERT trigger and inside the INFORMXI SP

e.g

Here the sample again.

-> Create Table

create table xtab ( a int, b char(10) );

Create TRIGGER ->
CREATE TRIGGER insertxtab
INSERT ON xtab
REFERENCING NEW AS n
FOR EACH ROW
(EXECUTE FUNCTION proc_xtab(n.a , n.b ));

-> Create PROCEDURE
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_xtab (a INT, b char(10) ) returning INT
RETURN a;
END PROCEDURE

insert into xtab values ( 1,"2")

Comment: In many databases including Informix it is difficult or impossible. I see few approaches. 1. Using "trace" in SPL procedure. Simplest but you can't format this as you wish. I wouldn't do that. This is designed just for logging to debug procedure logic 2. By creating UDR in java or C. I've never done this. Then you would call this UDR from trigger like SPL procedure. Probably too complicated. 3. As you've already written: by inserting data into the second table in SPL procedure and then unloading data from it. I prefer this approach.

Comment: There are few more options if you have Enterprise Replication: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=replication-push-data-feature, https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=api-smart-trigger-feature. For 14.10 there exist (does not require ER) also https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=guide-informix-change-streams-api-java . I haven't used any of this

Answer (score 1):

Finally we would be able to resolve the issue.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "informix".proc_xtab (a INT, b char(10) )
DEFINE os_command VARCHAR(100);
    LET os_command = ' ./sh_prep_text ' ||  a  ||  '  ' || b   ;
    SYSTEM os_command;
END PROCEDURE;
```

cat sh_prep_text

```
DATE_STAMP=`date '+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S'`
   TEXT_NAME="UNL_${DATE_STAMP}"
   echo "$1|$2|" > ${TEXT_NAME}
```

--> Table Schema

```
create table "informix".xtab
 (
  a integer,
  b char(10)
 ) ;
```

--- > Trigger info

```
Create trigger "informix".insertxtab insert on "informix".xtab 
   referencing new as n
    for each row (execute procedure "informix".proc_xtab(n.a ,n.b )
);



echo 'insert into xtab values(100,"VAL")' |dbaccess stores8

[informix@rss1 ~]$ echo 'select * from xtab ' |dbaccess stores8
```

a b
100 VAL

```
cat UNL_2023_01_30_10_31_24

100|VAL|
```

Thanks All for helping me to resolve the issue. !!